# How can I change the currency of my sandbox authorize net merchant?

Tags: payment

I'd like to change my currency at my sandbox authorize net merchant. I can only see one currency on my sandbox virtual terminal. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SE CiviCRM, The question you raised is basically for Authorize.net support team instead here. You will need to contact [Authorize.net support team](https://www.authorize.net/support.html) to change the currency for your merchant account.